# Python if statement errors while using inport random

Tags: python

I’m trying to use an if statement to determine if a certain text is in the input and that used to work fine until I used input random and now my if statement is returning a syntax error.

```
command_1=input()

post_type_fg="/post-fg"
post_type_ot="/post-ot"
post_type_sb="/post-sb"
post_type_gh="/post-gh"
post_type_hym="/post-hym"

import random
post_post_count= random.randint(1,10)
temp_post_like_count= random.randint(0,((post_post_count * 2))




if  post_type_fg in command_1:
        print("You posted",command_1[8:],"in the section forum games")
        print("Post Count:", post_post_count)
        print("Like Count: (", post_like_count, "*")

else: 
    
    print("error command 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is caused by previous line, i.e.:

```
temp_post_like_count= random.randint(0,((post_post_count * 2))
```

you have unbalanced brackets (more `(` than `)`). If you got `SyntaxError` but pointed line does not show any error then there is good chance, that problem is actually in previous line.